# Slim Framework - cannot add route middleware

Tags: routes, middleware, slim

I am new to Slim Framework and PHP. I cant get this to work, if I use a normal function and use "foo" as a parameter, it works, but doesnt work like this, even tho the documentation uses pretty much the same thing http://docs.slimframework.com/

```
<?php
    require 'Slim/Slim.php';
    session_start();

    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
    $app = new \Slim\Slim();


    $foo = function() {
       global $app;
        if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
            $app->redirect("/redirecto/login");
        } else {
            echo "Authenticated";
        } 
    }

    $app->get("/", $foo, function() {
        global $app;
        $app->render('index.php');
    });

    $app->get("/login", function() use ($app) {
        $app->render("login.php");
    });

?>
```

The error is

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$app' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\redirecto\index.php on line 41
```

*(the $app->get("/", $foo, function() { line )*

Answer (score 5):

I think the first thing I would say here is try to avoid calling you Slim instance as a global.

From the docs we actually call Slim getInstance method to get a copy of the current Slim instance. I will rewrite the code below, take a look at the docs and view some of the tutorials on [nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com/?s=Slim%20Framework) as they help.

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
session_start();

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();


$foo = function() {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $app->redirect("/redirecto/login");
    } else {
        echo "Authenticated";
    } 
}

$app->get("/", $foo, function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('index.php');
});

$app->get("/login", function() use ($app) {
    $app->render("login.php");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set it like this, declaring your function in a normal way and passing a string with its name to the router method. this will call `foo()` before it executes the router closure

```
function foo() {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $app->redirect("/redirecto/login");
    } else {
        echo "Authenticated";
    } 
}

$app->get("/", 'foo', function() use ($app) {
    $app->render('index.php');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have told you, the following is a bad practice

```
$foo = function() {
   global $app;
    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $app->redirect("/redirecto/login");
    } else {
        echo "Authenticated";
    } 
}
```

and you should instead declare it as

```
$foo = function() use ($app) {
```

**however**, regarding specifically to the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$app' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\redirecto\index.php on line 41
```

it's because after defining a closure in the way you did, you need to add a semicolon `}`. So your closure should become:

```
$foo = function() use ($app) {
   global $app;
    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $app->redirect("/redirecto/login");
    } else {
        echo "Authenticated";
    } 
};
```

Comment: Old question but IMHO it's worth mentionning that this is actually the only right answer to the oringinal question. The semicolon is someting easily missed when checking code but it is crucial. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your middleware as an anonymous function which creates it's own scope. In order to use the `$app` variable inside the function, you need to pass it into the scope with the `use` statement.

For example

```
$foo = function () use ($app) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
        $app->redirect("/redirecto/login");
    } else {
        echo "Authenticated";
    } 
}
```

You do the same thing with your routes further down in your code listing.